# php - textarea- html tags

Tags: php, html, textarea

I am new to programming with php.
I've done that:
There is a textarea that user writes text, and it is saved to db. But when listing the entries, the text with html tags are shown as html elements.

For example, "I'm < b >25< /b > years old" is shown "I'm **25** years old".

I want to show it as what user writes on textarea, not applying html rules. And due to this, user can not break multiple lines.

How can I avoid all html properties? is there any function or something else to help me?

Comment: help about multiple line breaks?

Answer (score 2):

Run the posted content through [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities):

```
$var = htmlentities($old_var);
```

Note: you should also be making sure you're not making yourself vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Save it to the database but escape every value that comes from a user to avoid mysql-injections.

Example:

```
$sqlaction = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (text) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text'])."')");
```

if you want to Show it on a page use htmlentities like this:

```
<div><?php echo htmlentities($row['text']); ?></div>
```